# Time complexity analysis of Python Scipy library

Tags: python, scipy, time-complexity

I'd like to calculate the time complexity of some algorithms that use [Python's Scipy library](http://docs.scipy.org/). I found a table for general Python functions in https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity that I plan to use. Is there a similar table for Scipy library?

Comment: I am not exactly familiar with Numpy and Scipy, but see this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html

Comment: Time complexity is not library specific. Only the underlying data structures and algorithms matter. Basically all you have to do is to look up the data structures/algorithms in a text book/wikipedia and you will find the time complexity for various operations.

Comment: @cel, if time complexity is not library specific, why there are complexity improvements among releases? For instance, this text is in release's page: "np.percentile has been implemented in terms of np.partition which only partially sorts the data via a selection algorithm. This improves the time complexity from O(nlog(n)) to O(n).". (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#percentile-implemented-in-terms-of-np-partition).

Comment: @MarcosdaSilvaSampaio, well okay. For most functions it is clear which algorithm is used under the hood. In this special case it's actually not clear and you would have to look into the source code. I don't think there's a document that lists the complexities of all functions.